# How to perform recaching using memcached?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

I am using memcached to cache a table records. My code is as follows

```
Rails.cache.fetch('custom_profiles') do
 @custom_profiles=CustomProfile.where(:status=>"Active") 
end
```

But whenever a new record has been added , its not getting updated.I want to update this variable whenever the table got edited. If you have any idea about this please share with me.

Comment: Have you look into Fragment Caching guide? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching You could expire your cache fragments `custom_profiles` in your controller in the create action w/ `expire_fragment`

Comment: Besides `create`you have also to consider when `custom_profiles` are `updated / deleted`. I suggest to not cache the objects but the fragments of the view representation of each object. See this [article](http://signalvnoise.com/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works) from dhh.

Comment: can we expire a cache from another controller?

Comment: yes most definitely @pooja agarwal

Answer (score 1):

You can delete an item from cache like this

```
Rails.cache.delete('custom_profiles')
```

You might want to do this in some callbacks or Observers

Comment: the answer is not respect to my question. it's a answer for my comment question. so i upvoted.